# How to get Sentence From Long String which contains specific Word using PHP

Tags: php

I know How to check if a string contains a specific word

```
if (str_contains('How are you', 'are')) { 
    echo 'true';
}
```

But I am looking for give search result like below to my users

[image]

so if my string is like below

> Paragraph development begins with the formulation of the controlling
> idea. This idea directs the paragraph’s development. Often, the
> controlling idea of a paragraph will appear in the form of a topic
> sentence. In some cases, you may need more than one sentence to
> express a paragraph’s controlling idea.

and then if my user search with word like `idea directs` then I want show result like `This idea directs the paragraph’s development`

I do not have idea which PHP function can help me for achieve my goal. Let me know if anyone here can help me for achieve my goal. Thanks!

Comment: Why not write some code to achieve this? You could split the string into sentences, check which one matches, and print that

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple function to achieve this directly. You will have to write an algorithm to get it done. Something similar below.

```
$text = "Paragraph development begins with the formulation of the controlling idea. This idea directs the paragraph’s development. Often, the controlling idea of a paragraph will appear in the form of a topic sentence. In some cases, you may need more than one sentence to express a paragraph’s controlling idea.";
$search = "idea directs";
$sentenses = explode(".", $text);

for($i = 0; i < sizeof($sentenses); $i++){
    if(strpos($sentenses[$i], $search))
        echo $sentenses[$i];    
}
```

convert the text into lowercase will help you to search case-insensitive,